# How to input/use float through Entry box tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to learn about tkinter so i create small GUI python to input 2 numbers and use their `tk.Entry()` box to input number and find the sum of both. But I fail to update the float number and generate their sum. Can anyone help add some components so to make it work? When i generate the result , it only show 0 which is the initial value of variable.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Shear and Moment Diagram Calculator")
operator=""

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=400,width=500,bg="White")
canvas.pack()
frame=tk.Frame(root, bg="Light Blue")
frame.place(relwidth=0.9,relheight=0.9, relx=0.05, rely=0.05)

num1 = float()
num2 = float()

tk.Label(frame, font =("Helvetica", 20),
        text="Number 1:" ).grid(row=0)

tk.Label(frame, font =("Helvetica", 20),
        text="Number 2:" ).grid(row=1,column=0)

num1= tk.Entry(frame, textvariable = num1 ).grid(row=0, column = 1)
num2= tk.Entry(frame, textvariable = num2 ).grid(row=1, column = 1)

def generate():
    num3= num1 + num2
    print(num3)


generate=tk.Button(frame, text="result", height="2", width="10",
                   fg="Black", bg="yellow", command = generate )
generate.grid(row=2, column=2)

mainloop()
```

Comment: don't you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `textvariable` has to be `tk.StringVar()`, `tk.IntVar()` or `tk.DoubleVar()`

Comment: don't use the same name for function `def generate()` and button `generate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `StringVar()` for textvariable to accept a floating point numeric string and then convert them to float using `float()` inside the `generate` function.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Shear and Moment Diagram Calculator")
operator=""

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=400, width=500, bg="White")
canvas.pack()
frame=tk.Frame(root, bg="Light Blue")
frame.place(relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.9, relx=0.05, rely=0.05)

tk.Label(frame, font=("Helvetica", 20), text="Number 1:").grid(row=0)

tk.Label(frame, font=("Helvetica", 20), text="Number 2:").grid(row=1,column=0)

# define entry variables
n1 = tk.StringVar()
n2 = tk.StringVar()

# assign the StringVar to the entry widget textvariables
num1= tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=n1)
num1.grid(row=0, column=1)
num2= tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=n2)
num2.grid(row=1, column=1)

def generate():
    # get the entered value from the entry field and convert it to float and then add
    num3 = float(n1.get()) + float(n2.get())
    print(num3)

generate=tk.Button(frame, text="result", height="2", width="10", fg="Black", bg="yellow", command=generate )
generate.grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the GUI and the result of floating number addition:

[image: GUI]

> You can also use `DoubleVar()` to accomplish this task.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Last time i used ' StringVar' instead of ' tk.StringVar' which is not working. XD

Comment: If you import tkinter using an alias name like `import tkinter as tk` then you need to use `tk.StringVar()` else if you use `from tkinter import *` the you can just use `StringVar()`. So it actually depends on how you import `tkinter`.

Comment: Noted , will be careful next time.

Answer (score 5):

`textvariable` needs `tk.StringVar()`, `tk.IntVar()` or `tk.DoubleVar()`

Using `StringVar()` you can convert value using `float()`, calculate sum and put it back in other `StringVar()` assigned to `Label()` or `Entry()`. You can also display text `"Error"` if values will be incorrect.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def generate():
    try:
        result = float(num1.get()) + float(num2.get())
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        result = 'error'

    num3.set(result)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

num1 = tk.StringVar()
num2 = tk.StringVar()
num3 = tk.StringVar()

tk.Label(root, text="Number 1:").grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Number 2:").grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Result:").grid(row=2, column=0)

tk.Entry(root, textvariable=num1).grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=num2).grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=num3).grid(row=2, column=1)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=generate)
button.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you So much, last time i use ` StringVar() ` instead of `tk.StringVar()` which result with " can't covert string to float".

Comment: if you try to convert `float("hello")` then you get error `"can't convert string to float"` - the same if you don't use `.get()` to get string from `StringVar()` - and it doesn't matter if you use `StringVar()` or `tk.StringVar()`